# Menu like Dropbox app in android

Tags: android

I like to make a menu in my Android app that works similar to the new popup menu in the dropbox app, i.e. when I click a button I want the menu to appear from bottom, like in the following image.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PupopWindow. When you click the button show your pupopWindow at the bottom.

Comment: I'll check on that. I accept your answer when I see that it fits my needs. Thanks.